# Pagination after search in php

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a search button which is used to search in category and product table.
So I am using 2 dropdowns when the page loads in first dropdown its showing the categories and when the user select the category in second dropdown it shows the product which are in that category. Also when the page loads the default query runs which is showing all the products. So the search function is working well.

The issue is I am also using pagination. Before searching, the pagination works fine (15 records per page) but after search if I select a category and search, it shows all the records of that category and when I go to next page it runs the default query and shows the default result. I want it to show the result of which I searched.

```php
<?php 
            $listperpage = 15;
            $c = $_POST['category'];
            $n = $_POST['product'];
            if(!empty($c)){
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = '$c'";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_query());
            }
            else if(!empty($c) && !empty($n)){
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = '$c' AND rank_name = '$n'";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_query());
            }else{
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_query());
                echo "else one";
            }

            $result_num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            //total pages
            $pages = ceil($result_num/$listperpage);
            //which number the user is crrrently on 
            if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $page = 1;
            } else{
                $page = $_GET['page'];
            }
            //sql limit starting number of results on th page
            $strt_limit_no = ($page - 1)*$listperpage;

            if(isset($_POST["search"])){
                $c = $_POST['category'];
                $n = $_POST['product'];

                if(empty($c)){
                    echo "<span class='form-error'>Select Category first!</span>";
                }
                else if(!empty($c) && !empty($n)){
                    $queryn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = '$c' AND rank_name = '$n' LIMIT ". $strt_limit_no .','. $listperpage;
                    $results =  mysql_query($queryn) or die (mysql_query());
                }
                else{
                    $queryn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = '$c' LIMIT ". $strt_limit_no .','. $listperpage;
                    $results =  mysql_query($queryn) or die (mysql_query());
                }
            }
            else{
                $queryn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category LIMIT ". $strt_limit_no .','. $listperpage;
                $results = mysql_query($queryn) or die (mysql_query());
                echo "else end";
            }
        ?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#category").on('click',function(){
            var category = $(this).val();
            if(category){
                //alert('3213');
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'process.php',
                    data:'category=' + category,
                    success:function(html){
                        $("#product").html(html);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div align="center" class='maintabledivdaily' style='width:100%; padding: 20px 0 15px 0;' >
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="80%" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="9" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">List of all Ranks</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)): ?>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr align="center" dir="rtl" style="font-style:">
                    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div class="pagination">
            <?php
            for ($page=1; $page <= $pages ; $page++) { 
                echo '<a style="color: #000000;
                        float: left;
                        padding: 8px 16px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        "href="list.php?page='. $page .'">'. $page .'</a> ';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add one more button to clear search? If it possible then you can save posted data $_POST['category'] & $_POST['product'] into the session and check if session is available than you have to apply where clause. and clear the stored session on click of clear-search button.   
The second approach is that you can send data via GET instead of POST, and if data is available then append this to pagination link, after page.

Comment: @AlokMali I want to go for second approach, can you give me the code example of how I can do that.

Comment: Your first 2 ifs have a problem. `if (!empty($c)){} else if (!empty($c) && !empty($n){}`. If I'm not mistaken, the `else if` will never execute, because if `$c` is not empty, it will go into the first `if` and if `$c` IS empty, then it will not execute either the `if` or `elseif`. (I don't think this is causing your issue, but I noticed it)

Comment: And `mysql_query` is deprecated and should not be used. I highly recommend [`PDO`](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo); But as it currently sits, your script is open to sql injection, since the variables are printed directly into your statment without `mysqli_real_escape_string` or (better yet) paramaterized queries with PDO or mysqli

Comment: I've been staring at your code for a bit, and I can't figure it out. I'm not totally sure what is happening here. It might help to separate your code into two scripts. One script for the default query and another script for the categories. I also don't see the html for the category selector nor the html which your ajax request is dependent upon (the elements with `id=category` and `id=product`.

Comment: @bro1o1, I have posted an answer. You can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your form method from post to get, where you have category selection and search button.

```
<form method="get"></form>
```

Get category and other posted values on server end.

```
$c = $_GET['category'];
$n = $_GET['product'];
```

add these values to pagination

```
<div class="pagination">
        <?php
        $cat = $prod = '';
        if(!empty($_GET['category'])){ $cat = '&category='.$_GET['category']; }
        if(!empty($_GET['product'])){ $prod = '&product='.$_GET['category']; }
        for ($page=1; $page <= $pages ; $page++) { 
            echo '<a style="color: #000000;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 8px 16px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    "href="list.php?page='. $page. $cat. $prod .'">'. $page .'</a> ';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Note : If 'page' parameter is not sending on search ,then set an input named page in your search form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>"
```

The second approach is that you can store posted values in SESSION and clear the session on clicking of a new button clear search.

Step 1 : Add a new button(Clear Search) besides Search button.

Step 2 : Store posted category and product into session and use this session in queries. And destroy session on clear search button.

```
        <?php
        $listperpage = 15;
        $_SESSION['category'] = $_POST['category'];
        $_SESSION['product'] = $_POST['product'];
        /** clear_search is the name of your clear search button */
        if(isset($_POST["clear_search"])){
            unset($_SESSION['category']);
            unset($_SESSION['product']);
        }
        if(!empty($_SESSION['category'])){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = ". $_SESSION['category'];
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_query());
        }
        else if(!empty($_SESSION['category']) && !empty($_SESSION['product'])){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = " .$_SESSION['category']. " AND rank_name = ". $_SESSION['product'];
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_query());
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_query());
            echo "else one";
        }

        $result_num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        //total pages
        $pages = ceil($result_num/$listperpage);
        //which number the user is crrrently on 
        if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = 1;
        } else{
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        //sql limit starting number of results on th page
        $strt_limit_no = ($page - 1)*$listperpage;

        if(isset($_POST["search"])){
            if(empty($_SESSION['category'])){
                echo "<span class='form-error'>Select Category first!</span>";
            }
            else if(!empty($_SESSION['category']) && !empty($_SESSION['product'])){
                $queryn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = " .$_SESSION['category']. " AND rank_name = " . $_SESSION['product'] . " LIMIT ". $strt_limit_no .','. $listperpage;
                $results =  mysql_query($queryn) or die (mysql_query());
            }
            else{
                $queryn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category WHERE fk_id_category = " .$_SESSION['category']. " LIMIT ". $strt_limit_no .','. $listperpage;
                $results =  mysql_query($queryn) or die (mysql_query());
            }
        }
        else{
            $queryn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_category.id = tbl_product.fk_id_category LIMIT ". $strt_limit_no .','. $listperpage;
            $results = mysql_query($queryn) or die (mysql_query());
            echo "else end";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: So this is not working @AlokMali. The search is not working now and pagination is woking but after going to page 2 it's showing the default result and showing the result of query in else. Can you tell how do it with session?

Comment: @bro1o1, Although first solution should work as well, but I have posted another solution.

Comment: @bro1o1, have you got the solution what you wanted? Is it working now?